# Synchronization in Multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.Files;


public class Main implements Runnable
{
    static String[] entries;
    static int count;
    static HashMap<String,String> finalMap;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        count = 0;

        File f = new File("rd.txt");
        String contents = Files.toString(f, Charsets.UTF_8);
        entries  = contents.split("\n");

        finalMap = new HashMap<String,String>(entries.length);

        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            Runnable temp = new Main();
            Thread t = new Thread(temp);
            t.setName("thread"+i);

            t.start();

            threads.add(t);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            threads.get(i).join();
        }

        System.out.println(finalMap);
        System.out.println(finalMap.entrySet().size());

        Set<String> set1 = finalMap.keySet();
        System.out.println(set1);
        System.out.println(set1.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {

            String temp ;
            System.out.println("Thread active "+Thread.activeCount());
            System.out.println("Count by thread: "+count + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if(count <entries.length)
            {
                synchronized(this) 
                {
                    temp = entries[count];
                    count++;
                }

                System.out.println(temp);
                String info[] = temp.split("[|]");
                synchronized (this) {
                    finalMap.put(info[0], info[1]+"written by "+Thread.currentThread().getName());  
                }

            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

There are entries in the rd.txt which follow the following formatting 

k1|v1,v2
k2|v3,v4
k3|v5,v6
.
.
.

I have used Google guava library for reading the text file ( just FYI ). So the aim of the program is to read a huge data set using multithreading. but when i run the code i run into arrayoutofboundexception though i have used synchronization on count variable so it must never cross the limit right? so any help regarding this will be helpful.

Also the number of entries read fluctuate on every run..

Comment: i also tried by creating a separate class that contains an integer,  and created an objeect and used Synchronized on that and still faced the same problem

Comment: count is static so it is not guarded by  synchronized (this)

Comment: @user1121883 Yeah, the `synchronized(this)` block does not protect the `count++` statement, but the root cause is not that `count` is `static`.  The root cause is that there is only one `count`, but every thread synchronizes on a different `this`.  Yeah, the reason there's only one count is because it's `static`, but it's the only-one-ness, not the static-ness that causes the problem:  You'd have the same problem if `count` was a non-static member of some object that was shared by all of the threads and referenced through non-static instance variables.

Comment: @jameslarge I know; I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is not thread-safe, and you are not protecting it adequately.  also, your test of count and entries is outside of a synchronized block, which is not thread-safe (and the synchronized block around count/entries is also incorrect).  `this` is going to be a different for each thread (since you have different `Main` instances).

Comment: can you suggest me, what should be the working code..actually i am new to multi threading! so help will be really great. thanks

Comment: @KungFu_Panda - [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @KungFu_Panda - unless you are being forced to use synchronized blocks, i'd look into a BlockingQueue, which is purpose built for this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous anwsers, you should learn to use the java java.util.concurrent.Executors rather than manage your threads by hand. You should equally read your file line by line within the thread in order to save the JVM memory.

My proposition of code is:

```
public class Main {
    private static final int NB_THREAD = 10;

    private static Map<String, String> finalMap =
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>()); // Synchronized map
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(); // Synchronized counter
    private static BufferedReader buffer; // Line Reader

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("rd.txt");
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Thread pool executor
        ExecutorService ececutors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NB_THREAD);
        List<Future<?>> futures = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREAD; i++) {
            // Submit line reader to the executor
            futures.add(ececutors.submit(new DataLineReader()));
        }
        for (Future<?> future : futures) {
            // wait the end of the run
            future.get();
        }
        // close the resource
        buffer.close();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of lines " + counter.get());
        System.out.println("Map size " + finalMap.entrySet().size());
        System.out.println(finalMap);
        Set<String> set1 = finalMap.keySet();
        System.out.println(set1);
        System.out.println(set1.size());
    }

    static class DataLineReader implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String temp = buffer.readLine();
            while (temp != null) {
                    counter.incrementAndGet();    

                    System.out.println("Thread active " + Thread.activeCount());
                    System.out.println("Count by thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    System.out.println(temp);

                    String info[] = temp.split("[|]");
                    finalMap.put(info[0], info[1] + "written by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                    temp = buffer.readLine();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Throwables.propagate(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```